# how to send audio/video data uri from browser to a file in S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I have an implementation that uploads an audio/video blob upload to S3 using putObject.
Let's assume obj contains the following data:

```
object {extension: "webm", type: "video/webm", 
contents: "data:video/webm;base64,GkXfo0AgQoaBAUL3gQFC8oEEQvO…"}
```

where contents is the video data URI (a base64 string). 
The server side code is:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
obj.contents = obj.contents.split(',').pop();
buffer = new Buffer(obj.contents, "base64");

var params = {
 Bucket: S3_BUCKET + "/videos/",
 Key: fname, // add new name 
 Body: buffer,
 ACL: 'private', 
 ContentType: obj.type
};
s3.putObject(params, handler);
```

If I want to do this on the client-side, how do I go about passing the base64 string
to putObject? There is no such thing such as Buffer in javascript.
I see that putObject expects either a  `new Buffer('...') || streamObject || 'STRING_VALUE'`,
but is the `STRING_VALUE` and option for audio/video files, or it is only for text?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I'd like to thank the AWS team for helping responding this question. It seems that, though not well documented, putObject() **does accept** Blobs or any native typed arrays (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=539115). This means that you can directly take any Blob in your browser (e.g. audio or video) and upload it directly to an S3 file.

```
audioBlob = this.GetAudioBlob()
var params = {
              Bucket: "MYBUCKET",
              Key: "audio_file_test.wav",
              Body: audioBlob,//this hast to be a string                                                        
              ACL: 'private',
              ContentType: 'audio/wav',
          };
s3.putObject(params, function(err,data){ console.log(err); } );
```

audioBlob in exactly a Blob object. `Blob {type: "audio/wav", size: 262188, slice: function}`