# Audio Files Stored in S3 are not Playable

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, next.js

I can successfully upload audiofiles to `AWS S3`, however the files do not play whether downloaded or played in the browser. The files do have a `filesize`.

I'm uploading an `audioBlob` object to `AWS S3`:

```
const [audioBlob, setAudioBlob] = useState(null)


const submitVoiceMemo = async () => {
    try {
      await fetch('/api/createVoiceMemo', {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: audioBlob
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
```

This is the `API` Route:

```
module.exports = requireAuth(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_1,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      region: 'us-east-2',
      signatureVersion: 'v4'
    })

    const s3 = new AWS.S3();

    const uuid = randomUUID()
    const s3Params = {
      Bucket: 'waveforms',
      Key: `voicememo/${uuid}.mp3`,
      Body: req.body,
      ContentType: 'audio/mpeg',
      ACL: 'public-read'
    }

    await s3.upload(s3Params).promise()

  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: e.message })
  }
})
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271618/how-to-send-audio-video-data-uri-from-browser-to-a-file-in-s3) question, I have confirmed that `req.body` is a `string`.

The file being received by `S3` has a `filesize` and the correct `contentType` when checked in the `S3 console`. It just isn't playable when downloaded or played directly in the browser.

---

Below is how `audioBlob` and also `audioFile` (an MP3) are generated (Basically the user records a voice memo and when they click `stopRecording`, raw audio is stored as `state`):

```
const [audioBlob, setAudioBlob] = useState(null)
const [blobURL, setBlobUrl] = useState(null)
const [audioFile, setAudioFile] = useState(null)

const stopRecording = () => {
    recorder.current
      .stop()
      .getMp3()
      .then(([buffer, blob]) => {
        const file = new File(buffer, 'audio.mp3', {
          type: blob.type,
          lastModified: Date.now()
        })
        setAudioBlob(blob)
        const newBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        setBlobUrl(newBlobUrl)
        setIsRecording(false)
        setAudioFile(file)
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }
```

**How can I correctly store audio generated on the front-end, in `S3`?**

Comment: Try playing the blob locally - is the blob generated even valid? If no, then it's got nothing to do with S3. If it is, then see if you can download the file manually from the console and play it. Is it playable? I

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary in the `stopRecording` function above, `blobURL` is created from the `blob`, and this is passed to an `audioPlayer`, which does play the audio in the browser. I tried passing `blobURL` to `S3`, but the resultant file is only `63B`, and it also doesn't play. `audioFile`, which is the actual `MP3`, also doesn't play when passed to S3 :/